# Class variable in a AsyncTask showing wrong value

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Im trying to call AsyncTask from a loop and to update class varbile for my AsyncTask.

My problem is that `programPosition` is not updating by is real value and only give me is

the last value from the loop.

Watch at my logcat `programPosition` is getting updated in my loop but my AsyncTask gets

only the last value of `programPosition`

Thanks for helping.

Here is my code and my log cat:

```
class CreateNewWorkout extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            if(pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing() == false)
            {   
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(DatePage.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Saving...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Creating product
         * */
        protected Void doInBackground(String... args) {

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            String[] list = dataPorgram.getExParameter("" + programPosition);

            Log.d("programPosition", ""+programPosition);

            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("exercise", list[0]));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("weight", list[1]));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("reps", list[2]));

            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_food,
                    "POST", params);

            if (json == null) {
                Log.d("is null", "null");
                return null;
            }
            // check log cat fro response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully created product

                    Log.d("ok", json.toString());;
                } else {
                    // failed to create product
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(Void file_url) {
            if(pDialog != null)
                pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
```

This is the loop im using in other method

```
for (int j = 0; j < arrayLength2; j++) {

                    String weight = "";
                    if (helping > 0) 
                    {
                        check1 = true;
                        check2 = true;
                    }

                    if (allWeights[j][2] == 0) {
                        double temp;
                        if (check1)
                            temp = allWeights[j][0] + (allWeights[j][1]);
                        else
                            temp = allWeights[j][0];

                        allWeights[j][0] = temp;
                        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
                        weight = df.format(temp);
                        if (temp == 0)
                            weight = "";
                        else
                            weight = df.format(temp);

                    }

                    else if (allWeights[j][1] == 0) {
                        double temp;
                        if (check2)
                            temp = allWeights[j][0] + (allWeights[j][2] / 100)
                                    * allWeights[j][0];
                        else
                            temp = allWeights[j][0];

                        allWeights[j][0] = temp;
                        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
                        if (temp == 0)
                            weight = "";
                        else
                            weight = df.format(temp);
                        Log.d("weight is ", ""+temp);
                    }

                    programPosition = dataPorgram.setProgramPlan(today,selectedDay, weight, j);

                    Log.d("programPosition", ""+programPosition);


                    new CreateNewWorkout().execute();
```

My logcat:

```
07-12 15:53:40.131: D/programPosition(9020): 181
07-12 15:53:40.151: D/programPosition(9020): 182
07-12 15:53:40.161: D/programPosition(9020): 183
07-12 15:53:40.161: D/programPosition(9020): 184
07-12 15:53:40.171: D/programPosition(9020): 185
07-12 15:53:40.181: D/programPosition(9020): 186
07-12 15:53:40.181: D/programPosition(9020): 187
07-12 15:53:40.191: D/programPosition(9020): 188
07-12 15:53:40.201: D/weight for server(9020): 70.36
07-12 15:53:40.201: D/programPosition(9020): 188
07-12 15:53:40.841: D/Create Response(9020): {"message":"Product successfully created.","success":1}
07-12 15:53:40.841: D/ok(9020): {"message":"Product successfully created.","success":1}
07-12 15:53:40.851: D/weight for server(9020): 70.36
07-12 15:53:40.851: D/programPosition(9020): 188
07-12 15:53:41.332: D/Create Response(9020): {"message":"Product successfully created.","success":1}
07-12 15:53:41.332: D/ok(9020): {"message":"Product successfully created.","success":1}
07-12 15:53:41.332: D/weight for server(9020): 70.36
07-12 15:53:41.342: D/programPosition(9020): 188
07-12 15:53:41.732: D/Create Response(9020): {"message":"Product successfully created.","success":1}
07-12 15:53:41.732: D/ok(9020): {"message":"Product successfully created.","success":1}
07-12 15:53:41.752: D/weight for server(9020): 70.36
07-12 15:53:41.752: D/programPosition(9020): 188
07-12 15:53:42.253: D/Create Response(9020): {"message":"Product successfully created.","success":1}
07-12 15:53:42.253: D/ok(9020): {"message":"Product successfully created.","success":1}
07-12 15:53:42.263: D/weight for server(9020): 70.36
07-12 15:53:42.263: D/programPosition(9020): 188
07-12 15:53:42.763: D/Create Response(9020): {"message":"Product successfully created.","success":1}
07-12 15:53:42.773: D/ok(9020): {"message":"Product successfully created.","success":1}
07-12 15:53:42.773: D/weight for server(9020): 70.36
07-12 15:53:42.773: D/programPosition(9020): 188
07-12 15:53:43.284: D/Create Response(9020): {"message":"Product successfully created.","success":1}
07-12 15:53:43.284: D/ok(9020): {"message":"Product successfully created.","success":1}
07-12 15:53:43.294: D/weight for server(9020): 70.36
07-12 15:53:43.294: D/programPosition(9020): 188
07-12 15:53:43.684: D/Create Response(9020): {"message":"Product successfully created.","success":1}
07-12 15:53:43.684: D/ok(9020): {"message":"Product successfully created.","success":1}
07-12 15:53:43.694: D/weight for server(9020): 70.36
07-12 15:53:43.694: D/programPosition(9020): 188
07-12 15:53:44.205: D/Create Response(9020): {"message":"Product successfully created.","success":1}
07-12 15:53:44.205: D/ok(9020): {"message":"Product successfully created.","success":1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using this value on multiple threads? If the value is an int replace it with an AtomicInteger that on is thread safe. For object you could use an atomicreference.

Above solutions will allow you to update values spread across multiple threads and read them safely. If you want to access (update but also read) data that is changed in another thread you need to do some synchronization on that data. The doInBackground method is running in a different thread and should not access data from other threads unless this is properly synchronized.

Can you explain what you are trying to do? because it is not at all clear to me what the purpose of your program is.

Comment: Thank you for answering.

Im trying to send data to my server. I read the data to send to the server from a loop.

I didnt know about the synchronization issue.

I solved my problem by sprate my work into two different threads. I dont know why it working, but it works...

Comment: I do need to add a note to not manipulating data in the AsyncTask. It is safe to do this on the onXXX methods, onProgressUpdate, onPostExecute, onPreExecute etc. just not in doInBackground, or methods called from there.